# Unable to understand the lambda expression in python code

Tags: python, lambda, expression

Hi I have a problem with this python code :

```
def func():
    m=max(d1.values()
    return list(filter(lambda t: t[1]==max(d1.values()), d1.items()))[0][0]
```

here it returns the max value of dictionary : 
    `dic={'a':1, 'b':2 ,'c':3}`

I am unable to understand the expression :

```
list(filter(lambda t: t[1]==max(d1.values()), d1.items()))[0][0]
```

please help me out I am new to programming

Thanks!

Comment: Read about lambdas here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp

Answer (score 0):

The filter function is returning an iterator of the element in the second argument for which the function (the first argument) returns true (as per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)). The element in the second argument are passed one by one to the function.

In your case the lambda is checking if the passed element of `d1.items()` is equal to the value of the biggest element of that list of values, `max(d1.values())`.

I hope this clarifies it for you.

Comment: Thanks mucio what you explained is correct that I understand but I didn't under stand the expression and specially 'lambda t=t[1] 'what does this mean

Comment: `lambda` just means anonymous function, a function that you are not going to invoke anywhere else beside that. The variable before `:` is the argument of the function, after is what the function will return, you can read it like `def function(t): return t[1]==max(d1.values())`. Let me know if this clarify a bit for you, in case I will add it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating your clarification but it would be nice of you if you could please elaborate it a bit more as I am very new to programming  please .

Comment: Well, in that case we should find a better channel, StackOverflow is not for this kind of basic explanation, for that you could find a nice python book or a website like the one linked by Tim Woocker

Answer (score 0):

First of all the code snippet to find the highest-value item from a dict should be like below

```
dic = {'a':1, 'b':2 ,'c':3}
reduce(lambda x,y: x if x[1] > y[1] else y, dic.iteritems())
```

Explanation:

The number of arguments after lambda is single for filter and map but 2 for reduce.
All filter, map and reduce expects an iterable object to be passed as 2nd argument

An example for filter is

```
list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
```

Here iteration occurs over the list [1, 3, 4, 5, 6], at each iteration a value is passed to the anonymous lambda function. In the above case it is **x**
The lambda method checks x % 2 == 0, and return True/False. If it is True then filter take the item else avoid the item and form another list. In this case only even number values are selected and get rid of odd values.

You could understand more about lambda and these functions of you play around with them. You can get questions from w3school or hackerrank or other websites